# Python: Displaying video in slow motion

Tags: python, video, slowmotion

I'm currently working on an experiment that requires participants to respond, as fast as possible, to a number which gradually appears on the screen (the opacity rate changes over time) by pressing the corresponding button on the keyboard. For each of the presented numbers, a video was created (e.g., 0 that gradually appears on screen). On my own laptop, I managed to play these movies in slowmotion by specifying the bitsMode when creating the Python window. However, on the experimental computers in our lab (Python version 1.82.00), I get a warning that 'bitsMode' is deprecated.

I'm still relatively new to Python, so I haven't been able to figure out a different (and probably more sophisticated) way of doings this. Does any of you know a way to play these videos in slowmotion (e.g., speed * 0.75)?

Kind regards,

Roel van Dooren

```
event.Mouse(visible = False)
preTrialPause = [0.1, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
blocks = 3
trialnum = 0

countDown(3)
win.update()

for block in range(blocks):
    for eachmovie in movies:
        trialPause = choice(preTrialPause)
        sleep(trialPause)

        mov = visual.MovieStim(win, movieFolder + eachmovie['Movie'], 
                                    flipVert=False, flipHoriz=False, loop=False)
        # Clear keyboard buffer.
        event.clearEvents(eventType = None)

        starttime = time()

        while mov.status != visual.FINISHED:
            mov.draw()
            win.flip(clearBuffer = True)
            for key in event.getKeys():
                responseTime = str(time() - starttime).replace(".",",")
                trialPause = str(trialPause).replace(".", ",")

                if key in ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']:
                    win.update()
                    trialnum+= 1
                    if key == eachmovie['Movie'][3]:
                        response = 'Correct'
                    else:
                        response = 'Incorrect'
                    mov.status = visual.FINISHED

        if trialnum == 10 and block == 0 or trialnum == 10 and block == 1:
            trialnum = 0
            presentText(win, "\n\nVerplaats je nu weer naar de andere computer. We gaan door met het volgende geheugen-geur blok.")
            response = waitText(win, "")
            presentText(win, "\n\nEr zullen opnieuw langzaam cijfers op het scherm verschijnen. Zo gauw je het cijfer waarneemt, moet je zo snel mogelijk op hetzelfde cijfer op het toetsenbord drukken. Gebruik hiervoor alleen de cijfers rechts op het toetsenbord (het numpad). \n\n\nNogmaals, het gaat bij deze taak om snelheid, dus druk zo snel mogelijk het overeenstemmende cijfer in.\n\n\nDruk op enter om te beginnen!")
            countDown(3)
            win.update()
            break

        elif trialnum == 10 and block == 2:
            presentText(win, "\n\nVerplaats je nu weer naar de andere computer.")
            response = waitText(win, "")
            break
core.quit()
```

Comment: There is no *"Python version 1.82.00"*. You might mean [PsychoPy](http://www.psychopy.org/index.html) a software written in Python programming language. If you data is recorded at normal speed then you could interpolate it (e.g., double fps) and show the resulting high fps video at normal speed to emulate slow motion.

Comment: I think that you should take a look into the following link https://www.codespeedy.com/creating-a-slow-motion-video-using-opencv-in-python/.